# Render module block programmatically

Tags: theming, 8

I know I can render my custom block programmatically with

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(2);
$vars['contact_us_info_block']= \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
$vars['contact_us_info_block'] = drupal_render($vars['contact_us_info_block']);
```

Now I want to render SimpleNewsletter  Block programmatically,I tried

```
$block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$config = [];
$plugin_block =  $block_manager->createInstance('simplenewssubscription', $config);
$vars['newsletterblock'] = $plugin_block->build();
```

but faced with following message in output

```
This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to enable the original module.
```

SimpleNewsletter module is enabled,**how can I render contributes modules block programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I render it with following snippets and work correctly

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('simplenewssubscription');
$block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
$vars['newsletterblock'] = $block_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example from [Block Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_token) to render block based on its id:

```
/**
 * Renders the block.
 *
 * @param  string $bid
 *   Block Id.
 *
 * @return string
 *   Rendered block.
 */
function block_token_block_render($bid) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);
  $block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
  return \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($block_content);
}
```